# Get the Date from DateTime object String in JSON response from backend

Tags: reactjs, json

I am working on a React JS project where my state is getting updated with date object string from the backend JSON response. I am getting a Date Time object in form of a string which looks like this:

```html
createDateTime: "2022-02-08T14:17:44"
```

The "createDateTime" object is assigned to my react js state, but when I show that updated state in the Browser UI, I get this:

```
2022-02-08T14:17:44
```

I want to display just the date, not the time stamp that comes along with the JSON string response. Is there any method that I can use to display just the Date?

```
2022-02-08
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create some helpers to show exactly what you need. How about something like this?

```
function DateTimeParser(date?: string) {
  if (date === undefined) return date;
  const dateTime = new Date(date);
  const parsedDate = `${dateTime.getDate()} ${
    dateTime.getMonth()
  } ${dateTime.getFullYear()}`;
  return parsedDate;
```

You can amend this to show exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) on your date value should get the result you want but first of all, you will need to parse the date you get from the server:

```
const parsedDate = new Date(responseDate)
const date = parsedDate.toLocaleDateString()
```

You can optionally pass to `toLocaleDateString()` the desired locale (in case you want to get the date in the format which differs from your local one)